# Array to string conversion error while moving data from one table to another

Tags: laravel, controller

I am trying to move data to recyclebin table and delete from user table at the same time while having the above mentioned error. So far i had tried the code under as

```
 public function deleteUser($id)
 {
        $recycle=User::where('id',$id)->first();

        $cycle = new RecycleBin();
        $cycle->name = $recycle->name;
        $cycle->email = $recycle->email;
        $cycle->user_type = $recycle->user_type;
        $cycle->save();
        User::where('id',$id)->delete();
     return redirect()->back()
             ->with('message','Deleted Successfully');
 }
```

anyone who can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this function, its based on the example you showed in your question.
Its better the pass the user as a parameter instead of looking for it in the function. A deleteUser function should delete a user and shouldnt search for a user.

I named the recyclebin $bin so its easier to understand that we are working with a recyclebin.

```
public function deleteUser(User $user)
{
    $bin = new RecycleBin();
    $bin->name = $user->name;
    $bin->email = $user->email;
    $bin->user_type = $user->user_type;
    $bin->save();
    $user->delete();
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Deleted Succesfully');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using where, php gives you an array, for having only one object you can use `first()` for example:

```php
User::where('id',$id)->first()->delete();
```

as suggest you can do this:

```php
$recycle->delete()
```

another suggest is to use **soft delete**